# C++ check gcc compiler flags while compiling

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-flags

Is there any way to find out compiler flags in C++ while compiling?
For example, some dream code:

```
#ifdef -fPIC
...
#endif
```

OS: Debian
Compiler: gcc

Comment: No, and neither should you need to. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to find out size of type (for example, wchar_t).

Comment: What problem are you having with `sizeof(wchar_t)`?